# Reactivate the Desktop function

Tags: desktop, pantheon

Since the day I installed elementary OS, I miss my classic desktop layout (files on your Desktop, not only blank space) and I'd like to reenable it. Does anyone know how to do that?

This here is probably against elementary OS's, or rather Pantheon DE's , thoughts but I worked with that layout since I started using computers, and I want to keep working with it. If there's no option, this might be an idea for Loki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution here worked very well for me on first try: http://mylinuxideas.blogspot.de/2015/04/enable-desktop-icons-and-right-click-on.html (I was setting up a skylake intel NUC i3 with elementary and OSX Yosemite theme for my wife to make the transition from a mac as easy as possible for her. BTW: I LOVE this little setup with elementary! Works like a charm.)

Comment: I used Nemo instead of nautilus, but the idea to use another Desktop Manager is great! Thanks :D